# Possible to send SQL Reporting Services report in email format with a duplicate pdf attachment?

Tags: email, pdf, reporting-services, html-email

Our system sends a "Daily Update" email via Reporting Services to all users each morning.  If people are on a computer there's no issue.  But, for users on the go, some mobile device email clients can't render the email.  However, they can all render pdf files.

So... the quick fix was to create two subscriptions for each user; one with the message in the body and one with the message in an attached pdf.  This creates an annoying amount of friction.  I'd love to send a single email with the message in the body a duplicate pdf version attached.

Is there a simple solution?

FYI, we're managing this through [Reporting Services Subscriptions](http://jesborland.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/the-power-of-reporting-services-subscriptions-for-delivery-e-mail/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, no: you can't have both formats in one email

The report "render format" determines whether inline or attached if you check "Include Report". So setting to "PDF" will generate an attachment. However, if you check "Include Link" for PDF rendering then folk can click and go to the report served by the Web site.

Otherwise, you'd have to write some small app that calls the ReportServer service and gets both report formats and combine into one email. Or write your own [custom delivery extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154050.aspx)

Comment: gbn has this exactly right. If you really need both versions of the report in one email, then you'll need to write some code to create the emails yourself. SSRS will only send one type at a time through its' subscriptions and out of the box delivery extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use **[Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx)**. You can manage it to send `e-mail` or `SMS` or even both of them to your subscribtion list.

I'm not sure that you can `send a single email with the message in the body a duplicate pdf version attached.`

Comment: This is nothing to do with SSRS emails

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want to send an email with attachment in pdf and this pdf will have same text/data as that in email body, right?
If that is the case then don't you think "Include Report" with "Render Format" in PDF will give you desired result?