# Sending Excel attachment & Body in same email SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssis

Is there a way to send an SSRS report in the body and a excel file using the subscription option?

I am using VS 2013 and I have an SSRS report but I need to include an excel file with some extra information (this file is refreshed with an SSIS package) so I need to send the current SSRS report and the file in the same email

any idea/solution?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I tried this a while back. Here is a link to a similar question with more detail than I was willing to write up (For what it is worth I solved this in a service agent process using the ssrs api to render both html and pdf formats and manually generate the emails for subscriptions *requiring* both formats) -->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783908/possible-to-send-sql-reporting-services-report-in-email-format-with-a-duplicate

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround I've used to do this in the past. You can use a Data-Driven subscription. In the query, return HTML formatted data. This can then be passed into the Comments box which goes in the body of the email. This way you can still include the actual Excel attachment.

Obviously, this takes some work and is not very efficient since it runs a separate query. But it is possible. Just be careful to keep the HTML to a minimum since different mail clients may display it differently.